# Mod_rewrite is adding /var/www to the resulting url

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with the Apache mod_rewrite rules. Whenever I try to go to `https://example.com//` (see double slashes at the end) it redirects to a 301 page but it's adding the location of the directory, i.e. `https://example.com/var/www/my-domain.com/html` which is not desirable.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /views/pages/404.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ views/pages/contact.php [NC,L]
```

Same happens when I go to `https://example.com//contact-us`

`https://example.com/contact-us//` is redirecting well to `https://example.com/contact-us` and `https://example.com//contact-uss` is redirecting well to the 404 page.

If one needs further information let me know.

Comment: Cross-site post on StackOverflow where this question already has an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236444/mod-rewrite-is-adding-var-www-to-the-resulting-url

Comment: @MrWhite Since it's off-topic there, and on-topic here, the answer probably should be here too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok, I've copied my answer here as well (and _edited_ to combine the "update").

Answer (score 1):

*Copied from [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245426/369434) to the same question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236444/mod-rewrite-is-adding-var-www-to-the-resulting-url*

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You are missing the slash prefix on the *substitution*. This results in a relative-path substitution (since the `$1` backreference does not contain the slash prefix), to which mod_rewrite prefixes the directory-prefix (ie. `/var/www/example.com/html`). This would result in the malformed redirect you are seeing. The `RewriteRule` should be written as:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

(The `^` anchor on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is unnecessary here.)

However, the following redirect is also invalid:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*) [L,R=404]
> ```

You are missing the *substitution* argument altogether. `[L,R=404]` will be seen as the *substitution* string (not the *flags*, as intended). This would also result in a malformed rewrite/redirect. The `RewriteRule` should be written as:

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404]
```

Note the `-` (single hyphen) is used as the *substitution* argument (which is later ignored). When specifying a non-3xx response code, the `L` flag is implied.

---

However, I'm curious what it is you are trying to do here, as you appear to be "accepting" multiple slashes in one directive (by *reducing* them), but then rejecting multiple slashes in another directive (with a 404)? Why not reduce all sequences of multiple slashes wherever they occur in the URL-path?

For example, replace the following (modified code):

```
# Remove trailing slash from URL (except files and directories)
# >>> Why files? Files don't normally have trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Reject multiple slashes later in the URL or 3+ slashes at the start of the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404]

# Reduce multiple slashes at the start of the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

With something like the following (depending on requirements):

```
# Reduce sequences of multiple slashes to a single slash in the URL-path
# NB: This won't work to reduce slashes in the query string (if that is an issue)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Remove trailing slash from URL (except directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that I've reversed the directives so that slashes are reduced before the final trailing slash is removed.

Note that the regex `\s[^?]*//+` specifically checks for multiple slashes in the URL-path only, excluding the query string. This is important if multiple slashes could ever *legitimately* occur in the *query string*, since the `RewriteRule` directive only reduces multiple slashes in the URL-path. Otherwise you would get a redirect loop.

Test with 302s to avoid caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing.